# Power BI Dashboard - Filters (checkbox and drop-down list)

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I have created Power BI reports using various visualizations and filter options. But from what I know, I've only been able to pin the visuals to the Dashboards and not the filter options. Is that correct? Or can we actually add filters, especially the checkboxes and the drop-down lists, on the final dashboards as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'Slicer' option in the visualization pane to get some similar options that you have in filter pane.

[image: slicer]

Answer (score 1):

Per Microsoft website:

> No. Can't filter or slice a dashboard. Can filter a dashboard tile in
> focus mode, but can't save the filter.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/service-dashboards

Power BI "Dashboards" are not meant to have the same features as "Reports". The Dashboards are supposed to be high-level snapshots with low-level of interactivity. If you want more details, you click on one of the visual to go to the "Report"

Comment: Ok, that's great to know. In that case, how does the permissions work? I've always only created and edited reports. So, I am trying to understand the process of sharing the report/dashboard with other business users. Can I grant only the read only access to the business users on the reports? Will they still be able to use the filters?

Comment: You can share you report to the stakeholders and grant access for read/write.

And their is feature for subscribe to the powerbi report. Its sending latest report at that time to selected stakeholders.

And you can share your dashboard to the stakeholders with powerbi licence. If they dont have licence they can only see image view of current dashboard, otherwise they can use every features you can do after deployment.

Comment: So that's an issue .. because I would want the business users to have access to use filters on the report but a complete read/write access would mean that by mistake, they might make any changes to the report. Is there a way like on Tableau/Cognos, the users can filter and slice on the dashboard itself? Or filter on the report but without a complete write access on it?

Comment: You can have users that are viewers only in the report workspace, and can't make alterations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-roles-new-workspaces